# Ethernet transformer differences

Tags: ethernet, hardware

Good morning,

I have a design using these magnetics over here to filter and isolate the ethernet signal: https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/336/-515468.pdf

And I have this other component as an alternative:
http://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/sm13072apel.pdf

My question is if they are fully compatible. The only difference I find is the marking on the polarity of the transformers (in the isolation transformer). Package and pinout are compatible

Comment: Nothing is fully compatible at the extremes. Without knowledge of what your circuit is and your performance expectations, comparing data sheets is a waste of time.

Comment: *The only difference I find is the marking on the polarity of the transformers (in the isolation transformer).* Well you're not reading very carefully then, are you! The inductance is different, the measurement ranges are different. But not very different. As they're both sold for ethernet use I would guess they are both suitable for ethernet use. Certainly for 10T, possibly for 100T, unlikely for 1000T

Comment: Sorry, probably I didn't use the right words. I agree nothing is fully compatible and that there are differences in the parameters (I read them :P). I am talking about the higher level (schematic diagram) with the dot marking. I would like to know if that difference could make a difference. Just to make it simpler. Consider the first magnetics I am using (not the alternative) and change the marking on the schematics as in the alternative. Would that make a difference in the design if you consider the rest of the system as a black box?

Comment: Btw it is used for 100T ethernet

Answer (score 1):

These **both are compatible with IEEE 802.3**. Also, excluding minor differences in the recommended footprints, these **both are interchangeable with each other**.